# How to highlight 3 consecutive cells w/ a 0

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, highlighting

I want to highlight cells when the row has 3 consecutive (or more) 0s. I only want to highlight cells with a 0, and only if there are at least 3 consecutive zeroes. The cell values are from a formula.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Conditional Formatting Solution. You have not mentioned what version of Excel you have. This solution works in Excel 2013 and should also work in lower versions ideally. The interface could be slightly different though.

I am assuming that you do not need to go up to the very last column in a row. Else a slight change is needed. To get this working I have suggested 3 conditional formatting rules. For say row 3 you need to put a condition for cell A3, a condition for Cell B3 and three conditions for rest of the cells in that row  (Excluding the very last two columns).

Rule in A3

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(A3),A3=0,ISNUMBER(B3),B3=0,ISNUMBER(C3),C3=0)
```

Rule in B3

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(B3),A3=0,ISNUMBER(B3),B3=0,ISNUMBER(C3),C3=0)
```

3 Rules in C3

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(C3),C3=0,ISNUMBER(D3),D3=0,ISNUMBER(E3),E3=0)
=AND(ISNUMBER(C3),C3=0,ISNUMBER(B3),B3=0,ISNUMBER(D3),D3=0)
=AND(ISNUMBER(C3),C3=0,ISNUMBER(A3),A3=0,ISNUMBER(B3),B3=0)
```

Now copy C3 and using Paste Special option Copy only the Formats up to the intended cells in that row that has data in it. You only need to copy the format, this way your formula in respective cells and the actual values are intact.

I have excluded the very last two columns. As they again need separate Conditional Formatting. If desired, you need to make a comparison of Last cell with previous two and second from last cell with cells on either sides.

[image]